# Adding Meta Boxes while Registering a Post Type in a Class

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox, oop

I am trying to add a few meta boxes for a Custom Post Type through a Class. I am using the `"register_meta_box_cb"` parameter while registering the Custom Post Type to specify the callback function for adding meta boxes.

Sample code - (outline of my code) -

```
class ABC
{
  public static function add_customposttype()
  {
    $abc_o = new ABC();
    $abc_o->reg();
  }

  public function reg()
  {
    $args = array(
      "label" => "ABC",
      "description" => "New CPT",
      "public" => true,
      "register_meta_box_cb" => array($this, "meta_box_callback")
    );
    register_post_type("abc", $args);
  } 

    public function meta_box_callback()
    {
      $meta_fields = get_all_meta_fields();   //  This gets me an array of objects of classes 'c_box, b_box and a_box'

      foreach($meta_fields as $object)
      {
        add_meta_box($object->name, $object->label, array($object, 'render_meta_box'), 'abc', $object->context, $object->priority);
      }
    }
}

class c_box
{
  public $name;
  public $label;
  public $context;
  public $priority;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'c_box';
    $this->label = 'C Box';
    $this->context = 'normal';
    $this->priority = 'high';
  }

  public function render_meta_box($post)
  {
    echo "<p>This is a C Box</p>";    //  Never executes
  }
}

class b_box
{
  public $name;
  public $label;
  public $context;
  public $priority;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'b_box';
    $this->label = 'B Box';
    $this->context = 'normal';
    $this->priority = 'high';
  }

  public function render_meta_box($post)
  {
    echo "<p>This is a B Box</p>";    //  Never executes
  }
}

class a_box
{
  public $name;
  public $label;
  public $context;
  public $priority;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'a_box';
    $this->label = 'A Box';
    $this->context = 'normal';
    $this->priority = 'high';
  }

  public function render_meta_box($post)
  {
    echo "<p>This is a A Box</p>";    //  Never executes
  }
}
```

So I have different Classes defined for different meta boxes. I want all of them to have a common `render_meta_box` function so that I can create objects of all these Classes, put them in an array and traverse through it so that I can call the `render_meta_box` function for all of them one after the other.

Basically, a meta box will have its own class with a `render_meta_box` function and some other functions, and I can create an object of each of such classes and run their functions one after the other, thus making it easy to add new meta boxes in the future.

The problem I am facing is, when I define the `render_meta_box` method in separate classes with HTML code in it to be echoed, it looks like `add_meta_box` never executes that callback function. I tried to see if I could get it to print something in the `render_meta_box` method but it never reached that print statement.

Am I missing something here? I thought I could call the `render_meta_box` methods using different objects to have them all execute differently, is my approach incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you making multiple class? use one Class and add the code there. Do not need any separate class for every callback function.

Comment: Making a separate class for each meta box because each one's `render_meta_box` function is going to be different. For example, a checkbox meta box is going to be rendered differently than a select type one,

Answer (score 0):

and welcome!

It would be helpful to have code that is more complete and shows how you are calling these methods. However, one thing I see that is likely responsible for at least part of your problem is the way in which you are calling `add_meta_box()`.

`add_meta_box()` should be called during the `add_meta_boxes` action. I've never tried running it as a callback of `register_post_type()` before. But, assuming that you are running `register_post_type()` during `init`, I imagine that `add_meta_box()` would run during `init` too - before the function is available.

If WP is actually trying to run the `add_meta_box()` before it is available, you should be able to see a `Fatal Error` in your PHP logs because of calling an undefined function.

To troubleshoot, I'd first confirm that your `register_meta_box_cb` is working by simply having it call a function that will `die;` or write a something to a file.

After you confirm that it is working, you can try having the `register_meta_box_cb` call a function that will add an action to `add_meta_boxes`. Have the callback to that `add_meta_boxes` action run your `add_meta_box()` loop.

Let me konw if that doesn't work or you need some more help!

Comment: Registering meta boxes while registering a post type works fine. I got it to work, just that I was making a stupid mistake of using an incorrect variable name in the `add_meta_box()` function.

You can add meta boxes both ways, while registering a post type and also by using the `add_meta_boxes` action.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what was going wrong.

It was as trivial as an incorrect class variable name. I was using a variable called `field_label` in the class, and accessing it incorrectly like `$this->label`, which meant it had NULL value.

My approach to add meta boxes during the post type registration however works perfectly.